# Does a curly brace have a "but not more" operator?

Tags: regex, grep

**TL;DR:** *Do curly brackets provide a negative look-ahead ability to limit results to "not more than max results?"*

I can use curly brackets to specify a min and (optional) max number of characters to match:

```
[abc]{5}      // 5 characters
[def]{2,}     // min 2, but no max
[ghi]{10,20}  // 10-20, inclusive
```

This is nice for finding "merge conflict" lines in VCS output:

```
<<<<<<<
=======
>>>>>>>
```

where the pattern `^[<=>]{7}` is used.

But do curly brackets have a "but no more" option? Like something that would match this functionality: `^[<=>]{7}(?![<=>])`

In plain English: "7 characters of `<`, `=`, or `>`, but where the next character is not one of those."

Some comment blocks may look like this:

```
==================================
Some nicely-formatted comment here
==================================
```

The `^[<=>]{7}` pattern considers this a match because the first 7 `=` characters DO meet the criteria. A `\b` does not seem to work, since these characters don't qualify as "word boundaries". A `\s` partially works, because both the VCS output lines of `<<<<<<<` and `>>>>>>>` are usually followed by a space plus the branch name, and the `=======` is followed by a newline (which the `\s` technically matches), but that also captures that whitespace character itself.

Can curly brackets use something like `{n,m!}` where it matches at least `n` times, but does not occur past `m` times?

Or am I stuck with using look-ahead operators `(?!...)` or whitespace `\s`?

Comment: Usually you'd just match the next, non-brace character, yes.

Comment: Negative lookahead is the way to specify that the match shouldn't be followed by something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do curly brackets provide a negative look-ahead ability

No.

You hardly ever would need this, usually you'd just match the next character(s) which would be a non-brace anyway. If you do need it, you just append the negative lookahead explicitly.

Matching `^((<{7}|>{7})(\s\w+)?)|={7})$` in your case would just be fine.